# how can I make a div contains inside a flex div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a percentages based div  - and trying to contain a div inside a div. I want the center (xyz div) to be only 90% (height) of the size it get from content-div.

I would like the "content" div to be responsive to 90% height of the center div (between header and footer). Now - it over shoot based on browser size.

[image]

---

my code is https://jsfiddle.net/thbx4pv2/

css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
    font-size: 4em;

}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  flex: 0 1 30px;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}


.xyz {
    position: absolute;
  margin: 10 10 10 10  ;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

html

```
    <div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="xyz">
    <p>
      <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post an image of the final result you want?

Comment: post required image - http://imgur.com/J5rzMnb.  i would like the "content" div to be responsive to 90% height of the center div (between header and footer)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position attribute and Do the following changes for **xyz** class

```
margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
width: 90%;
```

Comment: that does not work for me. I need the xyz div to be 90% height / 70% width of content div

Comment: Then don't mention the height for this div and up and down margin should be 5%. Check if it works. Otherwise I will send you code . :) 
margin: 5% auto 5% auto;

Answer (score 0):

```
.xyz {
width: 70%;
box-shadow: 0 0 30px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-flex: 18 0 0; 
flex: 18 0 0; 
}
```

Check this again mate.
This way, you can have the header and footer fixed height if you like.
The Html is changed, ask if a change is not clear, and it does now exactly what you wanted, the borders are there just for showcase purpose.
The font size is set to very small because of the overflowing.
Let me know if this is the ideal solution.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmxmQE

Comment: thanks for the try. you are using hardcoded sizes - and I would like to use % only. is that an option

Comment: Ah ok, yes that is possible, I will just need a slightly different layout, the xyz can't be nested in the content div. I thought you would roughly know the height. I will do this right now and post it.

Comment: @hypermails
Check it out now, no heights declared anymore.:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `position: absolute;` you need to position the element you want it to be positioned against.

In your case, add `.content{position: relative;}` to your css.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/ro2tcezu/) with smaller fontsize.